# Two for loops are very slow - Java interpreter

Tags: algorithm

i need to iterate through an array of strings with the first loop and iterate through each substring (column) in a second loop:

How a string element looks like:

```
"abc|def|ghi|jkl|mno|pqr|stu|vwx|yz"

I% = 6000 //Amount of elements in my string array

//For each row
FOR ROW% = 0 TO I%
    //Set the ROW
    STRING$ = ARRAY$(ROW%)

    // For each Column per row
    FOR COL% = 0 TO 9
        //Set the actual Column
        SUBSTR$(STRING$, CHR$(31), COL% + 1)
        //Do something with the column
        ROW$ = ROW$ + STRING$
    ENDLOOP
ENDLOOP
```

I hope you can understand the syntax, it is nearly the same as BASIC.

Is there a way to make this code faster? With about 6000 entries in the array, it takes about 2 minutes to finish.

Comment: I don't think there is, sorry. The most optimised way of doing this that I know of would be doing as you did, going row by row and then column by column.

Comment: I am just asking if there is a way to make it faster - the code above does work, but it is slow in my opinion. Would that be so much code to speed it up ?!

Comment: If you're looking to make working **actual** (non-pseudo) code faster, [codereview.se] would be a better place to ask. If you're looking for a fundamentally different approach to your problem, you should explain the problem you're trying to solve in more detail, although if it's just an issue of conditionlessly iterating over an array, that already limits the ways you can do that to *basically* 1 way. That pseudo-code is extremely difficult to understand - you might want to opt for Java-esque pseudo-code instead.

Comment: How can this code work? Is that an actual language? If so, which language? Is this a custom language you wrote? What happens if you implement the same algorithm in a different language?

Comment: It is an java interpreter language, see http://ebusoft.de/

Comment: This line `ROW$ = ROW$ + STRING$` looks like you are adding the current substring to some ever-growing string. This operation can be very slow, and can get slower the longer that string gets (as you describe in some other comment). Depending on the language, there are faster ways to build strings, e.g. `StringBuilder` vs. `+` in Java.

Comment: You are right.....

Comment: BTW, I don't know the language, but what is the `SUBSTR$(...)` line doing? Shouldn't you bind the result to some variable? Aren't you adding the _original_ string to `ROW$` over and over again?

Comment: it gets and sets the substring of the given variable

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't give us real code nor a reference on the language / runtime envireonment, it's difficult to help you.

So just some generic answers:

If your program runs too slow, start with profiling your application. E.g. for Java there's the free JVisualVM contained in the JDK, or there are professional tools like JProfiler. The profiler tells you which part of your code is consuming the execution time (Like @tobias_k, I wouldn't be surprised if the profiler pointed you to the "ROW$ = ROW$ + STRING$" instruction, but we might as well be completely wrong).

Really do these measurements. You wouldn't believe how often developers thought the knew the reason fo their program's poor performance, invested considerable effort into improving that part of the program, just to see zero effect. So, have the profiler tell you what's the time-consuming part of the program.

When you know where's the critical spot, improve it either locally (if it were Java `row = row + string;`, changing `row` from `String` to `StringBuilder` would go that way). Or rethink your algorithm. If you have e.g. a O(2^N) complexity and can replace it by O(N^2), the gain will be huge.

I'm sorry that's all I can recommend without knowing the language and execution environment...

Comment: (@louis12356: If dissatisfied with a solution, jot down a guess to the main cause, but *don't act on a guess*. (If not already written down, fix what to be satisfied with: *goal*.) *Measure* (multiple data points, if at all possible, or at least multiple times: reproducibility)(and record …). Check your (mental) model. Change *one* thing (quick wins first) , make a note of the change you expect. Repeat from *measure* until *goal* is reached (or deemed unattainable).)

Comment: That's good general advice, but in this case, I think this _is_ the actual code (in some very obscure language), and I strongly doubt that there will be anything like a profiler for that language.

Comment: tobias is alright - i wast wanted to know, if there is any optimization for this code. And this language exists - but it is NOT in common!!!! There a just a few people in my country (germany) who use it. Thank your for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not the embedded loop here. 6000 elements are not a big deal nowdays. Either the computer/environment/language/interpreter you are using is very slow or the 'Do something with the column' part is very complex or implemented poorly.

Comment: I can say that it becomes slower as more elements are passed, so in the first 5 seconds, 1000 entries are done, but in the end, it takes up to 15 seconds for the last 200.

Comment: gonna check that.

Comment: `in the first 5 seconds, 1000 entries are done, [but it takes] 15 seconds for the last 200` information like this should go into the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a wild guess, but this line looks suspicious: `ROW$ = ROW$ + STRING$`

It looks like you are adding the current substring to some ever-growing string. This operation can be very slow, and can get slower the longer that string gets (as you described in a comment), as this will create a new string in each iteration of the loop, each time copying the content of the previous strings to a new memory location, and then discarding the old value to be garbage-collected, effectively giving you quadratic complexity in the inner loop.

Depending on the language you are using, there might be faster ways to build strings, e.g. StringBuilder vs. + in Java, or collecting the strings to be joined in a list and then using `''.join` in Python.

---

If that language does not have any other methods for joining large numbers of strings, you could try this: Store all the strings to join in a list, and then join that list in pairs, until everything is joined. This should reduce the complexity from O(n²/2) to O(n log n). See this example: Here, `+` is one of the existing `STRING$` you are joining, and `#` is a newly created string resulting from `ROW$ = ... + ...`, and the length of the blocks corresponds to the length of the strings to join (and the chunks of memory to copy around).

```
What you do now: O(n^2/2)     Pairwise-joining: O(n log n)
+ + + + + + + +               + + + + + + + +
## + + + + + +                ## + + + + + +
### + + + + +                 ++ ## + + + +
#### + + + +                  ++ ++ ## + +
##### + + +                   ++ ++ ++ ##
###### + +                    #### ++ ++
####### +                     ++++ ####
########                      ########

2+3+...+8 = 35                4*2+2*4+1*8=8+8+8=24
```

---

Finally, looking at the [website](http://ebusoft.de/) you linked to in comments, it seems like that code is translated to actual Java code, so you might take a look at that code (either in reading, or as suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45886135/1639625), with a proper profiling tool) to get a better understanding of the problem. You might also try to fix it in the generated Java code, e.g. using a `StringBuilder`, but those fixes will probably be lost when re-generating the code. All in all, I'd suggest just using Java in the first place, if that's an option.

Comment: yeah that would be nice, but i guess this language does not have something like this - im gonna check that.

Comment: @louis12356 You could ask their support team, but I'd probably rather just use a different language, if that's an option.

Comment: Your totally right, i just wanted to know if there is any optimization for the above code.

Comment: @louis12356 As I said, the problem is not so much with the algorithm but with the way you join the strings. There might be other ways to do that in that language, but I do not know the language.

Comment: @louis12356 There might be a way to speed up the join, even using just `+`; see my edit.

Comment: Seems like a solution, but i have no idea how to write it with this language :/

Comment: In old BASIC-like languages the bottle-neck is usually the memory-allocation. Try to find a way to compose the string in some kind of  pre-allocated object if it's possible. Also if you write down what do you want to do there exactly inside the loop, maybe there is a more specific optimized solution for it.